ggplot2: confidence intervals with geom_ribbon() not showing
I have the following data frame: the point estimates (beta_), the lower bound of the CI (lowerci_), and the upper bound (upperci_). I want to plot the estimates as points and an area without lines, just shading (and transparency, alpha), meaning the CI. But my code is not working even though it seems to work for people online.
library(ggplot2)

data <- readr::read_csv("round,beta_,lowerci_,upperci_,panel_round
0,-6.559555121299354e-10,-5.44198064389434e-9,4.130069619634469e-9,BL
1,0.029400043189525604,-0.21591313183307648,0.2747132182121277,HF01
2,-0.05057445541024208,-0.30436697602272034,0.20321807265281677,HF02
3,0.05245266854763031,-0.1334749162197113,0.23838025331497192,HF03
4,0.005192806478589773,-0.11910264194011688,0.1294882595539093,HF04
5,-0.017897112295031548,-0.21049267053604126,0.17469844222068787,HF05
6,-0.015306402929127216,-0.1945999711751938,0.1639871746301651,HF06
7,-0.058936167508363724,-0.22124320268630981,0.10337086021900177,HF07
8,-0.06648150831460953,-0.2282124012708664,0.09524938464164734,HF08
9,0.02168324775993824,-0.1671695113182068,0.21053601801395416,HF09
10,-0.04629828408360481,-0.1798108071088791,0.08721423894166946,HF10
14,0.03215331211686134,-0.12467528879642487,0.18898190557956696,END")

    ggplot(aes(panel_round, beta_)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "solid", color = "black") +
    geom_point(size = 5) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lowerci_, ymax = upperci_)) +
    labs(x = "",
         y = "Impact on Food Insecurity Experience Scale (reversed)") +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
    theme(panel.background    = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"), # set panel background to white
          plot.background     = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white") # set plot background to white (optional)
    )
)


You have a discrete x axis, try geom_errorbar instead of geom_ribbon.

It's not really clear what you want to see in your plot. As pointed out in the comment, your x-axis is currently categorical. The ribbon will only work well with a numeric x-axis.
Is the value in the round column significant? If so then you can use this and update your axis with the labels from the panel_round column.
ggplot(data, aes(round, beta_)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lowerci_, ymax = upperci_)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "solid", color = "black") +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = "Impact on Food Insecurity Experience Scale (reversed)"
  ) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
  theme(
    panel.background    = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
    plot.background     = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white")
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=data$round, labels = data$panel_round)

Changes:

The x aesthetic is round rather than panel_round.
Use scale_x_continuous() to label the x-axis.
Change the order of geom_ribbon() and geom_point() to ensure that the points are on  top of the ribbon.


